# Returning a Function Pointer in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers

Here is the code:

```cpp
void (*)(const dpp::slashcommand_t &event) operator[](const std::string &index);
```

When I compile this, I get the following error message:

```
In file included from commands_controller.cpp:3,
                 from main.cpp:2:
commands_controller.h:28:12: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
   28 |     void (*)(const dpp::slashcommand_t &event) operator[](const std::string &index);
```

Do you have any suggestion for how I can resolve this error?

Comment: The only sensible way to solve this is to create a type alias for your function pointer. I believe it is possible without one, but the syntax is tricky.

Comment: I've tried with type alias. It was " typedef void( * return_func)(const dpp::slashcommand_t &event)". It gave the error: "typedef does not define a type". By the way @tkausi, it is an operator overloading.

Comment: std::function (part of modern c++ for a while now) might save you some trouble

Comment: @PierreBaret -- indeed, but at the cost of some overhead. This is not it's primary use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When dealing with function pointers, use typdefs. The correct non-typedef syntax is:

```
void (*operator[](const std::string &index))(const dpp::slashcommand_t &event)
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4eabda845ac15a54

Obviously, this is completely insane.

So instead, always use a typedef or alias:

```
using slash_fn_ptr = void (*)(const dpp::slashcommand_t &event);
slash_fn_ptr operator[](const std::string &index);
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd96b9918b1526b7